# Reset CRON Job - Template + WAMP

Tags: cron, wamp, jobs

I've downloaded a template of an ADs site and I'm testing it on localhost with WAMP Server.

The problem is that the listings are not expiring after the end of their lifetime days.

I contacted the owner of the template and he said to reset the CRON job of my environment.

But I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WAMP you are running on Windows.

If you are running on Windows you dont have access to cron as there is no cron on Windows.

So the reason you are not getting listings expired is that the jobs designed to do the expiration are not running.

You will either have to run it on a UNIX system or work out what jobs should be run and set them uninmf PHP CLI and then create tasks to run them using Windows Task Sceduler.